# Sed/awk/perl match all prefixes of a given string

Tags: regex, grep, sed, awk, perl

I'd like to match all lines in a file that either my word is a prefix of, or the line is a prefix of my word.  For example searching for "abc" should match:

> a
>   ab
>   abc
>   abcd
>   abcxyz

but not:

> xabc
>   zzab
>   xaz

The "my word is a prefix of" part is easy, just match on "`^abc`" of course, but I haven't come up a solution for the "line is a prefix of my word" bit.  Tried something in awk but wasn't able to make the line contents a part of the regular expression.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `grep -e '^abc' -e 'abc$'`

Comment: That won't match the prefixes of "`abc`", but will match lines for with it is a suffix, like "`xabc`".

Comment: `egrep -E '^ab?c?'` ? Give us an example what you want as result

Comment: For that, you'd have to write `grep -E '^a$|^ab$|^abc'`

Comment: `grep -e '^a' -e '^ab' -e '^abc'`?

Comment: Alex and Janos:  Yes, I can obviously enumerate the prefixes on my own, but this becomes tedious when the search string has many characters.  I would also need to script it.

Comment: @Ossifer If you're scripting it, it's easy to create the regexp dynamically from the input, using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases you need to handle, where the line is shorter than your search string or where it's longer.

When it's longer, you want to test if the beginning of the line is equal to the test string.

When it's shorter, you want to test if the beginning of the search string is equal to the line.

In the cases where the lengths are equal, either method works.

```
awk -v search=abc 'length() > length(search) ? substr($0, 1, length(search)) == search : substr(search, 1, length()) == $0' inputfile
```

Comment: Perfect -- thanks!  I knew awk would be best, but didn't think of using substr instead attempting regex.